# curl to post a remote form and get the result in a var

Tags: php, curl

The following code is to post a remote form.

```
<?php
$post_data['mail'] = 'parcel';
$post_data['destination'] = '1';
$post_data['weight'] = '300';


foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) 
{
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);


$curl_connection = curl_init('http://app1.hongkongpost.com/calc/eng/overseas/step2.php');

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
//curl_close($curl_connection);
var_dump($reuslt);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));

?>
```

The result is NULL, but if I comment the line 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

the page return will return to 
http://app1.hongkongpost.com/calc/eng/overseas/step2.php
and show result(that means the post is successful), but I only want to get that table, and not return the result page. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. incorrect variable name $reuslt. replace: "var_dump($reuslt);" to "var_dump($result);"
2. add curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);